# How to display odd numbers in rows of 10 and columns of 5?

Tags: java, oop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int number = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row <=10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column <= 5; column++) {
            while(number<100) {
                if (number%2 == 1) {
                    System.out.print(number);
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
                number++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get is :

> 1  3  5  7  9  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37 
>   39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73
>   75  77  79  81  83  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99

How do I format them in 10 rows and 5 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    for (int row = 0; row <=10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column <= 5; column++) {
            while(number<100) {
                if (number%2 == 1) {
                    System.out.print(number);
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
                number++;
                if (number % 10 ==1){
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Output :

```
1  3  5  7  9  

11  13  15  17  19  

21  23  25  27  29  

31  33  35  37  39  

41  43  45  47  49  

51  53  55  57  59  

61  63  65  67  69  

71  73  75  77  79  

81  83  85  87  89  

91  93  95  97  99
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        if((row * 10 + column) % 2 != 0)
            System.out.print((row * 10 + column) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

EDIT:

Or try this more generic solution, you just have to set the amount of columns and rows you want:

```
final int ROWS = 10;
final int COLUMNS = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS * 2; column++) {
        if((row * COLUMNS * 2 + column) % 2 != 0)
            System.out.print((row * COLUMNS * 2 + column) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Or use `while` loops like this:

```
final int ROWS = 10;
final int COLUMNS = 5;

int row = 0;
while(row < ROWS) {
    int column = 0;
    while(column < COLUMNS * 2) {

        if((row * COLUMNS * 2 + column) % 2 != 0)
            System.out.print((row * COLUMNS * 2 + column) + "\t");

         column++;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    row++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your both `for` loops are useless they are doing nothing ,also the condition `number%2 == 1` is incorrect for checking the odd number , it will not work for negative numbers , but i congratz you for trying .

will you try

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
           if(i%2 != 0) {
               System.out.print("  "+ i+ " ");
           }
           if(i % 10 == 0)
               System.out.println();
       }
```

Comment: Im new to OOP btw

Comment: @Big_Smoke i can understand we all start somewhere, you can try this one it is simplest way to do that

Comment: To be honest the program wants number from 0 to 100. So negative numbers are excluded.

Comment: ok, but it was just for safer side , if you want to input loop negative numbers some day, it should work

Comment: Actually I wanted to use while loop because it's easier for me to understand compared to for-loops but just want to understand by using various combinations

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. I don't see why you need the two FOR loops.

```
int column = 0;
int number = 0;

while (number < 100) {
    if (number % 2 == 1) {
        System.out.print(number);
        column++;
    }
    if (column % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n");
    } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    number++;
}
```

Comment: My program wants it to be solved using nested for-loops only.